# How can I add HTML content using document.createElement() and appendChild()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

So I am creating a simple login page and have chosen to display a modal dialog that will state 'Logging you in...' and then have a spinning loader,

I can easily add the text I want with `document.createTextNode('Logging you in...);`.

My issue is that I don't know how to then add my CSS3 spinning loader underneath the text. Here is my code:

```
        <script>
          function activateModal() {
            // initialize modal element
            var modalEl = document.createElement('h2');
            modalEl.setAttribute("class", "modal-header");
            modalEl.style.width = '400px';
            modalEl.style.height = '300px';
            modalEl.style.margin = '100px auto';
            modalEl.style.backgroundColor = '#828282';
            modalEl.style.color = '#ffffff';

            // add content
            var loginTxt = document.createTextNode('Attempting to log you in...');
            modalEl.appendChild(loginTxt);

            // show modal
            mui.overlay('on', modalEl);
          }
    </script>
```

As requested;

https://jsfiddle.net/jackherer/ffghkc8k/

I'd like to be able to place a loader/spinner in there ? like this one ..

https://codepen.io/jackherer/pen/dpBzym

As I'm just beginning to learn javascript I would really appreciate any advice people

Comment: A jsfiddle or plunker would be so useful to answer this and see your current stage.. not everything but just this part of the requirement.

Comment: Apparantly "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post"!!! http://pastebin.com/CKM8LnRT REALLY ??? HERES THE DIFF PLEASE LOOK AND TELL ME ITS A DEVIATION FROM THE ORIGINAL QUESTION!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so this is what you will need. From your expected outcome in codepen, I've forked your jsfiddle and modified a bit [working example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64ra20b8/4/) . You already have the `scss` animation ready, so it's just adding to your modal box.

To add the spinner, update the `activateModal` script

```
function activateModal() {
// initialize modal element
var modalEl = document.createElement('h3');
modalEl.setAttribute("class", "modal-header");
modalEl.style.width = '400px';
modalEl.style.height = '300px';
modalEl.style.margin = '100px auto';
modalEl.style.backgroundColor = '#828282';
modalEl.style.color = '#ffffff';
modalEl.style.textAlign = 'center'; //Extra addition. You may remove this.

// A span element so you can add styling
var loginTxt = document.createElement("span");
loginTxt.innerHTML = 'Attempting to log you in...';
modalEl.appendChild(loginTxt);
modalEl.setAttribute("class", "loader");

//SPINNER START 
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'loader');
// For simplicity, I choose to use the svg content as inner html. You may create this as an element
newDiv.innerHTML = '<svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50"> <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg>';
modalEl.appendChild(newDiv);
//SPINNER END

// show modal
mui.overlay('on', modalEl);
}
```

Snip: [image: outcome]

To be honest you seem to have everything sorted. If you expected a diferent outcome let us know.

P.S: I understand :) You'll get used to it.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, I've been playing around with various things and failing each time, but after my edit was not rejected and you had the info needed it now works fine, again thanks, I really appreciate your help :)